# Why is re.sub is not replacing string with empty string

Tags: python, regex, string

I can't understand pythons re.sub behavior.  I want to replace an entire multi line string with nothing.  I want an empty string back:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = """hello
world 
good 
day
"""

    textarea = re.sub( '.*', '', data)
    print "processed '%s'" % textarea

    textarea = re.sub( '.*', '', data, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    print "processed '%s'" % textarea
```

The above code, at least on my machine does NOT output the following:

```
processed ''
```

This is for both cases, multiline/non-multiline.  Instead the single quotes are spread across multiple lines.  Why is this so?

What I really want to do is delete empty lines ( lines containing only zero or more spaces) from a multiline string, and I believe the above example is the issue.

Thanks.

**ANSWER:**

As others pointed out. MULTILINE was confusing me. To answer the original question, instead of just my desire, the dot was not matching the newline, hence everything was getting replaced with an empty string, except the newlines in the original string were left alone.

By adding the re.DOTALL flag to the above example gave the expected behavior of an empty string.

Comment: This works for me.  To match lines containing only zero or more spaces: `^ *$\n`

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't realize my cut and paste removed the breaks from data assignment.  I edit the post again to put them back in.

Comment: @Bitdiot what's your expected output?

Comment: Your description and the attempts are totally different.

Comment: Okay.  No surprise, I'm probably confused by something.

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem.  In your test you also need the flag `re.DOTALL` so that the `.` will match the newline.  Which is irrelevant to your real desire to delete empty lines.

Comment: Okay, my real desire is to delete empty lines, you're saying re.DOTALL won't do that?  Because it seems to work on the example I gave.  So I guess I'm confused.  Anyways, thanks for the DOTALL suggestion.

Comment: The `re.MULTILINE` flag is irrelevant for your pattern since it doesn't contain either of the `^` or `$` anchors. As dsh says, the flag you need is `re.DOTALL`.

Comment: Great thanks.  I see my confusion. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Bitdiot the `MULTILINE` flag affects how `^` and `$` behave;  the `DOTALL` flag affects how `.` behaves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I really want to do is delete empty lines ( lines containing only zero or more spaces) from a multiline string.

```
re.sub(r'(?m)^[ \t]*$\n?', '', s)
```

or

```
re.sub(r'(?m)^\s*$\n?', '', s)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mB5oJ5/1)

Comment: May i know the reason.

Comment: By the way, why do you need the '(?m)' in your answer?

Comment: `(?m)` multiline modifier. Used this instead of `re.Multiline`.